# Casting the return value of a base class as the inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm currently playing around with inherited methods. Now I have a base class called "BaseData" that is being inherited by 4 other classes, one of which is Category.

I have a helper method in BaseData that currently returns a datatype of BaseData. I am able to call the helper method from the inherited class but I added a cast to Category to it. Now I understand that even though the Category inherits from BaseData, they are two totally different classes. Is there a correct way to do what I am trying to do? Or is it even possible?

My base class looks like this

```
public class DataBase
{
    // Accessors and stuff

    internal static DataBase BindDataToInstance(DataRow dr)
    {
        var condition = new DataBase()
        {
            ID = (string)dr["ID"],
            Title = (string)dr["Title"],
            Description = (string)dr["Description"]
        };
        return condition;
    }


}
```

I'm thinking of calling the method by

```
    public class Condition : BaseData
    {
       public static Condition GetCondition()
       {

        return (Condition)BindDataToInstance(ConditionDal.GetCondition(conditionId));

       }
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Basically, I want to take an instance of the base class and turn it into an instance of a derived class

The code that Spook Kruger suggested is what I'm currently using - one BindDataToInstance method per class. Each are exactly the same except for the return type.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question, e.g. by posting some code?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need to add a cast.  You haven't really said what your trying to do, so it's impossible to answer whether or not there is a correct/possible way to do so.

Comment: Share code, it will very much help us to understand your goal. 

Also could you give a very specific question like: "I cannot get the class iLoveCats to inherit from iLoveDogs but I can get it to work from iHateDogs" Why is that? Or I cant get cats to talk to dogs at all? etc. 

Your question is harder to answer because it is like I made two animals one has two legs and the other doesnt how do they work?

Comment: What about a Generic class instead of Inheritance?

Comment: I'll look in to Generic classes. Thanks for the lead

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you read up on polymorphism and inheritance. What you are trying to do is possible dependant on your inheritance structure, unfortunately your code gives little information about how these classes are tied together.

My suggestion to solve your imediate problem would be to perhaps use a wrapper. if Condition takes in a DataBase as a parameter and sets all the values necesary then one could just do this:

```
public static Condition GetCondition()
{

    return new Condition(BindDataToInstance(ConditionDal.GetCondition(conditionId)));

}
```

Comment: The code you've provided is what I'm currently using. But I'll have that same block of code in each of the derived classes. I'll read on polymorphism tho. Thanks!